# Array formula to ouput project names

Tags: arrays, excel-formula

I am trying to use an array formula to look at column R and if column R says concepting- it will give me the list of project names in columns A that are currently in concepting.

The formula I am using is:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX('ACTIVE PROJECTS'!$A$1:$A$350,SMALL(IF(('ACTIVE PROJECTS'!$R$1:$R$350="CONCEPTING")),ROW('ACTIVE PROJECTS'!R$1:$R$350))ROW(2:2))),"")
```

It keeps telling me my formula has an error.

Can anyone help with the formula?

Comment: =IFERROR(INDEX('ACTIVE PROJECTS'!$A$1:$A$350,SMALL(IF('ACTIVE PROJECTS'!$R$1:$R$350="CONCEPTING"),ROW('ACTIVE PROJECTS'!R$1:$R$350)ROW(1:1))),("") I tried this formula too, with no luck

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. A misplaced bracket and a missing comma was all that was fouling up the works.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX('ACTIVE PROJECTS'!$A$1:$A$350,SMALL(IF('ACTIVE PROJECTS'!$R$1:$R$350="CONCEPTING", ROW($1:$350)), ROW(1:1))),"")
```

I tightened up the formula by using `ROW($1:$350)` in place of `ROW('ACTIVE PROJECTS'!R$1:$R$350)`. The [ROW function](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/ROW-function-3A63B74A-C4D0-4093-B49A-E76EB49A6D8D) doesn't actually care where the row number comes from.

Now, that is not a unique list; just a list of those projects that have a CONCEPTING value in column R. I suppose the nature of the data could make that list unique but the formula does not. A unique list is slightly more involved.